# Почему расположение элементов не соответствует действительности?

Tags: android, button, разметка

> **UPD**: Проблема решилась переключением вкладки с темами в AS на DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar

Доброго времени суток. Имеется следующая проблема: при разметке элементов в Android Studio, предпросмотр показывает одно расположение кнопок. При тесте приложения на реальном девайсе, кнопки располагаются по-другому, но суть в том, что действительности не соответствуют только кнопки, остальные элементы в порядке

**AndroidStudio**

> [image: Android Studio]

**Real Device**

> [image: это выглядит так на реальном устройстве]

**XML-разметка**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/companyLogo"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/slider" />

<ru.timuruktus.waroll.Model.ExtendedSliderLayout
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/top_join_alpha"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:text="@string/join_email"
    android:id="@+id/yourEmail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/companyLogo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="#fcfcfc" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editEmail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/yourEmail"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:text="@string/join_pass"
    android:id="@+id/yourPass"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editEmail"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="#fcfcfc" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editPass"
    android:layout_below="@+id/yourPass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="@string/join_join"
    android:id="@+id/join"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editPass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="@string/join_reg"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:background="#e3e3e3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/join_forgot_pass"
    android:id="@+id/forgottenPass"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотели, чтобы кнопки были друг под другом, разметка второй кнопки должна быть такая:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:text="@string/join_reg"
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_below="@+id/join"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
android:background="#e3e3e3"
android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />
```

Android Studio показывает расположение кнопок на экране определённого устройства. В окне редактирования XML можно выбрать, на каком устройстве и в каком положении экрана просматривать разметку. Естественно, на разных экранах расположение каким-то образом будет отличаться.